# Configure local filesystem storage for Loki

Tags: kubernetes, logging, grafana-loki

I'm running Grafana and Prometheus successfully on my microk8s cluster. I'm now trying to setup Loki. It's mostly working, however I'm still unable to configure the local filesystem. I'm using the loki-stack helm charts to deploy.

Here is what I did:

```
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack -f loki-values.yaml
```

And here is the content of `loki-values.yaml`:

```yaml
loki:
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  storage:
    type: filesystem
    filesystem:
      chunks_directory: /home/djipey/loki/chunks
      rules_directory: /home/djipey/loki/rules
  rulerConfig:
    storage:
      type: local
singleBinary:
  replicas: 1
```

The dir `/home/djipey/loki` exists on the machine and I chmoded it 777 so I don't expect any permission issues.

The setup above works, and I can create a Loki data source in Grafana, and it contains the data I expect. However, the `loki` folder stays empty. A describe on the loki pod hints that the storage config is ignored:

```
Volumes:
  tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  config:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  loki
    Optional:    false
  storage:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-w5tz2:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
```

Would you have any idea how to configure that please?

Edit:

@Petter I tried your suggestion. The possiblr config options for `singleBinary.persistence` are:

```yaml
  persistence:
    # -- Enable StatefulSetAutoDeletePVC feature
    enableStatefulSetAutoDeletePVC: true
    # -- Enable persistent disk
    enabled: true
    # -- Size of persistent disk
    size: 10Gi
    # -- Storage class to be used.
    # If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>.
    # If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning.
    # If empty or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    # set, choosing the default provisioner (gp2 on AWS, standard on GKE, AWS, and OpenStack).
    storageClass: null
    # -- Selector for persistent disk
    selector: null
```

So I tried:

```yaml
loki:
  auth_enabled: false
  commonConfig:
    replication_factor: 1
  storage:
    type: filesystem
  rulerConfig:
    storage:
      type: local
singleBinary:
  replicas: 1
  persistence:
    storageClass: local-loki
    enabled: true
    size: 5Gi
```

With the pv:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: loki-db
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /home/djipey/loki
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
  storageClassName: local-loki
```

But it doesn't work, it's never claimed:

```
NAME            CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                                                                                     STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
prometheus-db   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-db-prometheus-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-0   local                    37h
grafana-db      10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound       monitoring/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana                                                                  local-grafana            37h
loki-db         10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                                                                                             local-loki               18m
```

I'm a bit stuck here, there is nothing in the logs or the events that indicates that loki is attempting to use this storage.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Loki persistence config right is a rather complex story. First, you must understand the difference between the Pods file system and whatever have you on the host machine. `/home/djipey/loki` does not exist in the pod. The Loki helm chart in SingleBinary mode tries to create a persistent volume named "storage" and mount it to `/var/loki`, so the chunks and rules folder under `/var/loki`. How and what sort depends on your Kubernetes setup. In your case, it seems to be emptyDir, that is, disk storage but ephemeral. Perhaps you can you can set the `singleBinary.persistence.storageClass` value in the config to choose a host path storage class, such as `microk8s-hostpath` or select a preconfigured volume by using `singleBinary.persistence.selector`. I'm not familiar with the details of microk8s storage config, so you may need to dig a bit further into that.

Comment: I tried that but not much success, I updated my question if you want to have a look.

Comment: Ok I "found" the problem, the config above is supposed to work, but it just doesn't if Loki install from loki-stack. Installing Loki separately from grafana/loki and using this config just works.